# Date Picker view in React js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, calendarview

I need to create Date picker for reservation project in React Js. I need calendar view which left side row will show time with hours and upper days of the week[image: such kind of picker]). Unfortunately I could not find such component or npm package for using. Could you please suggest me any package which I can use for such kind of view.

Comment: You can take a look at the Ant Design's datepicker component : https://ant.design/components/date-picker/

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying that kind of datepicker does not exist but it sure is rare and could be something that might end up demanding you to create your own.

**What I would recommend is the AirBnb datepicker:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates

**You can look at this code example if reading the npm docs isn't clear:**
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

- Easy to use
- As for the times and everything maybe that could be a side logic that you could self when one has selected dates